# difficulty understanding syntax

Tags: objective-c

In the [tutorial](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/) there is the following declaration:

```
-(BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)useAuxiliaryFile;
```

I'm interpreting this as `writeToFile` method returns a `BOOL` result.  It takes 2 parameters.  The first is an `NSString` reference.  The second is the result of calling `atomically` and passing it a `BOOL` value.

Did I get that right?

The tutorial goes on to say you call the above method like this:

```
BOOL result = [myData writeToFile:@"/tmp/log.txt" atomically:NO];
```

which is find.  But I wonder if I MUST use "atomically:NO"

Could I have done something like

```
resultOfAtomically = atomically:NO
BOOL result = [ myData writeToFile:@"/tmp/log.txt" resultOfAtomically ];
```

assuming I declared `resultOfAtomically` properly.

Also, does prepending `@` to `"/tmp/log.txt"` mean something like "give me the reference NOT the value" ?

Comment: Regarding the @ before @"/tmp/log.txt", the @"" defines an NSString object whereas without the @, a simple "" defines a C-style string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text `atomically` introduces the second parameter of the `writeToFile:atomically:` method, it is not a separate function. Therefore, you cannot call simply `atomically:NO`. This would be correct, however:

`BOOL myBool = NO;`

`BOOL result = [myData writeToFile:@"/tmp/log.txt" atomically:myBool];`

When talking about Objective-C methods, you would not call this method "writeToFile", you would call it "writeToFile:atomically:". By this syntax you know that the method expects two parameters (one for each colon).

Here's a way to think about how the method declaration breaks down:

`-(BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)useAuxiliaryFile;`

`-` = defining an instance method (`+` would be for a class method).

`(BOOL)` = returning a boolean value.

`write` = this method is about writing something (nothing magic, just a friendly word choice - could have been `print` or something else).

`ToFile:(NSString *)path` = the first parameter of the method, path, is an NSString pointer and the friendly text "ToFile" (again just a word choice, nothing special) hints that I need to provide a file path for that parameter.

`atomically:(BOOL)useAuxiliaryFile;` = the second parameter of the method, useAuxiliaryFile, is a boolean and the friendly text "atomically" (still nothing special) hints that the boolean value determines whether or not to write the file atomically.

Comment: Still unclear.  

Is this a definition of the atomically method that belongs to the obj referenced by writeToFile?

Comment: There is no atomically method, atomically is only a parameter of writeToFile:atomically:. Here's another example with similar structure: `-(int)addThisNumber:(int)num1 toThisOne:(int)num2;` The method is `addThisNumber:toThisOne:` and "toThisOne" simply sets up the second parameter for the method. There is not a separate "toThisOne" method. In another language, your original method might be written like: (BOOL)writeToFile(string fileName, BOOL atomically); Objective-C just uses a different syntax for parameters.

Comment: Not trying to be a jerk, but in your example you said the method is addThisNumber:toThisOne and it contradicts the your statement that atomically is NOT a method in writeToFile:atomically

Was that a typo?

Comment: No contradiction: "addThisNumber:toThisOne:" is the full name of the method ... the *whole* phrase. Conversationally, you might refer to this as the "addThisNumber" method out of convenience, but technically the entire phrase is the method name. Similarly, it's easier to say "writeToFile", but the proper method name is "writeToFile:atomically:", again the whole phrase. The method could have been named (though not as accurately) "writeToFile:Now:" or "writeToFile:Bubba:". The point is that "atomically" is just part of the entire method name, it has no meaning on its own or outside the method.

Comment: I've reworded my answer to be more technically accurate and added a breakdown of how to read the method declaration. Hopefully this makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: This helps.  But its making me think of more questions.

Is splitting up of the method name due to more than 1 parameter?

Comment: Yes, for instance this method from `UITableViewDelegate` has four parameters and the text before each one is simply to make clear the purpose of the parameter: `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView performAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender`. Another language might define that sort of method like TableViewPerformActionForRowWithSender(tableView, action, indexPath, sender), Objective-C just spreads out the method name to provide a closer association with the parameters.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22854/discussion-between-user1126515-and-david-ravetti)